# AWS DMS service: creating target endpoint for S3 is throwing error Role is not configured properly.AccessDenied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-dms

I am creating configuring a AWS DMS to migrate my RDS database to the S3 bucket. I created the instance and the source endpoint. There was no issue creating them. Now, I am creating a target endpoint choosing the S3 as the source. Before I create the target, I created a new policy with the following content.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:PutObjectTagging"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::buckettest2/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::buckettest2"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Then I created a new IAM role called SharKyaMalS3FullAccess and I attached the policy I created to that role. When I create the target endpoint using that role. I am getting the following error.

```
SYSTEM ERROR MESSAGE:The IAM Role arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:role/SharKyaMalS3FullAccess is not configured properly.AccessDenied
```

[image]

What is wrong with my configuration and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your policy looks correct, so make sure when you create the IAM role you pick DMS as the AWS service. This will add the DMS service as a trusted entity.

[image]